# How I can upgrade my device to latest Android without SD card?

Tags: updates, 4.2-jelly-bean

I have a HCL Me u1 device that is running the 4.0.3 version of Android. I want to upgrade it to the latest version of Android.

I don't have an SD card. Are there any tricks for upgrading without one? How do I root the device and backup my old files?

I rooted my device with superuser, now I want to know how to upgrade to the latest version of Android. I downloaded the Zip from online but I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

To install the custom rom you need to have ClockWork Mod installed on the tablet/phone. ClockWork Mod is the software tool that installs the custom rom. See [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1963355) for information on how to install ClockWork Mod.